# Unable to open modal on initialization angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

```
/* COMPONENT */
import { Modal } from './../../common-components/modal/modal.model';
import { Buttons } from './playground.model';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import template from "./playground.component.html";
import style from "./playground.component.scss";

declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
    selector: 'app-playground',
    template,
    styles: [style]
})

export class PlaygroundComponent implements OnInit {
    vm = new Modal({
        id: 'vid-modal',
        customColor: '#F00',
        showHeader: true,
        showClose: true,
        dismissible: false
    });
    buttons = Buttons;
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.vm.actions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['open']});
    }
    modalReady() {
        this.vm.actions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['open']});
    }
    openModal() {
        this.vm.actions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['open']});
    }

}

/* HTML */
<vc-button [button]="buttons.save_btn" (click)="openModal()"></vc-button>

<vc-modal [modal]="vm" (modalReady)="modalReady()">
    <vc-modal-body>
        IS IT WORKING?
    </vc-modal-body>
</vc-modal>
```

I am trying to open a modal as soon as the page gets initialized using ngAfterViewInit.
I am also using an emitter inside the modal component which tells me when the modal has been initalized.
Even after all this i am unable to open the modal on initalization.
It only works on button click. **I do not wish to use any jQuery or third party solution**. I know this is an async problem but i am unable to solve it using observables/replay subjects.

Comment: Your component's class have to implements AfterViewInit:

export class PlaygroundComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

Comment: @Faly, this is not necessary, Angular recognizes these without having to say `implements...` :) These markups are more of a support for the developer (and IDE)

Comment: yeah there is no need for implements. But i am pretty sure the problem lies with actions since it is a normal subject and not a replay subject it is not getting initialized on time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export class PlaygroundComponent implements OnInit {
...
  ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.vm.actions.emit({ action: 'modal', params: ['open']});
    }, 1);
  }
...
}
```